# Export date report in PDF format and send it to email through outlook (Visual Basic 6.0)

Tags: vb6

Dears

Hope you are doing well .

I search through internet to find a solution to extract data report in PDF format in first stage and then send it to email using outlook but i did not found a clear solution for this so if there anyone can help me on this i will appreciate that .

I don'h have a code to share it with you .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Quick PDF Library Lite from Debenu](http://www.debenu.com/products/development/debenu-pdf-library-lite/)

I use it to open a base PDF file, add my dynamic data, and save it to PDF again.
I was looking for the project where I did it to post some code, but can't find it right now sorry